# How this two dimension array passing test fail?

Tags: c, parameter-passing

```
#include<stdio.h>

void test(int *TESTarr,int M,int N){
    printf("%ld\n",(long)TESTarr);
    printf("%ld\n\n",(long)*(TESTarr+5));
    //printf("%d\n",*(marr+1*N+2));
}
int main(){
    int myarr[5][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,10,11,12,13,14,15};
    int i,j;
    test(myarr,5,3);
    printf("%ld\n",(long)myarr);
    printf("%ld\n",(long)*(myarr+5));
}
```

here is an experiment to test two dimension array passing function. and the printf("%d\n",TESTarr) will print the address of TESTarr.

But why here I got a result below? I mean why the printf("%d\n\n",*(TESTarr+5)) and printf("%d\n",*(myarr+5)) don't output the same result?

```
1733315152
6

1733315152
1733315212
```

Comment: It is crucial to decide from where one should start answering this question!! I would suggest you to read [c-faq: Arrays and Pointers](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html)

Comment: Why should they output the same? (Both `printf` statements are undefined btw).

Comment: how does this even compiles? without a bunch of errors and warnings

Comment: You are passing a `int*[]` to `int*`

Comment: You do know that the `"%d"` is to print `int` values right? What do you think would happen on a machine where pointers are not the same size as the size of `int` (like just about *all* 64-bit systems)?

Comment: I got several warnings, but it will compile finally

Comment: Also, you are passing a pointer to an array of `int` to the `test` function, but it's declared to have its first argument as only a pointer to `int`.

Comment: Warnings are almost all of the time a sign of you doing something that you should not do, and are often indicators of where you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Fixing the *root cause* of the warnings will most likely fix your program. And the cause of your problems in the program you show in your questions is undefined behavior.

Comment: If you want to print pointers use %p instead of %d. Although you have passed a 2 dimensional array pointer to the `test` function you have effectively flattened the array to an array of ints. Dereferencing a pointer there will yield an int value. I think what you want is to tell the compiler that `test` takes a 2D array with 3 columns of ints per row. Something like this should give you the results you want int `void test(int TESTarr[][3],int M,int N){`. Please note that with 2D array `myarr+5` points to the 6th row (which is beyond the edge of the 5 row you have)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simple answer for why the values aren't the same is that myarr is an array of arrays of 3 integers, so when you add to its pointer, you're actually adding sizeof(int)*3.  TESTarr is just an array of integers, so adding to that adds sizeof(int).  The printed values are different because the pointers are different types.

This is a bit of a simplification, but and I would recommend reading up more on pointers, arrays, and their differences in the c-faq that was linked earlier.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass the 2D array then you should pass only its base address, and not myarr[0] to the function. passing myarr[0] is same like passing *(myarr + 0) to the function which is first 1D array of the 2D array. now if we again dereference TESTarr then it will get us element of 1D array which is integer. now *(TESTarr+5) is same as TESTarr[5], which will fetch 6th element starting from base address which is 6.

Comment: I think it is worth pointing out (for clarity) that in the `main` function `myarr+5` doesn't point to the 6th integer in the array. It points to the 6th row. Dereferencing with `*(myarr+5)` is a pointer to the first column of the 6th row which is the same as `*((myarr+5)+0)`. Dereferencing that once more would attempt to get the int value at the 6th row, 0 column which will be undefined